# How to use variable from another function (Python and TKinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Context: I am working on a program that takes text from the user to process it and prints it out as a PDF.

```
def enterData():
    data = la1entry.get()
    textInPre = data
    sumMecha(textInPre)
    
def textPDF(text):
    a4=210
    chW=2.45
    wTex=a4/chW
    pdf = FPDF(orientation='P', unit='mm', format='A4')  
    pdf.set_auto_page_break(True, 10)
    pdf.add_page() 
    pdf.set_font(family="Arial", size=15) 
    splitted = text.split('.')
    
    for line in splitted:
        lines = textwrap.wrap(line, wTex)
        if len(lines) == 0:
            pdf.ln()
        for dot in lines:
            pdf.cell(0, 5.5, dot, ln=1)

    pdf.output("Done.pdf") 
"""
    directory = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('PDF File', '*.pdf')], 
                                                        defaultextension='.pdf',
                                                        initialdir='C:',
                                                        title='Summary')
"""

def sumMecha(textInPre):
    textInPre = textInPre.replace("[ edit ]", "")
    done = ' '.join(textInPre)  
    global done
    #textPDF(done)
    #print(done) 
    #return done
```

So, **enterData** function calls out the **sumMecha** function to take the text and start processing it and the same works for **sumMecha** and **TextPDF**.

```
button1 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Start processing data", command=enterData)
button1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=10)

button2 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Export PDF", command=textPDF(processed))
button2.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=10)


window.mainloop()
```

The issue lies when i attempt to separate the processing function **sumMecha** and the text to pdf one **textPDF**.
Attempting this will fail to execute the program, because i have failed to access the **done** variable.
I have succeded in doing this by chaining them all into one button,  but working on separating the processing in one button, and the exporting into another button.
I worked with the **return** function and **global** function but to no avail.

1- How can i call the **done** variable to cram it into the **textPDF** function?
2- Is it possible to cram a **save as** prompt into the **textPDF** function?

Comment: It's not clear to me what sort of issue you are having. However, in order for `done` to be accessible in the global scope, it needs to be *declared* in the global scope, even if it has a value of `None`. Basically, put `done = None` (or `done = <whatever initial value>`) in the global scope (above the declaration of `button1 =  ...` perhaps). Then your functions can access `done` as needed. If they need to modify the value of `done`, add `global done` after the function definition and before the modification step.

Comment: I have tried your method of declaring the global variable before the modifications, though i get promped by: "Name 'done' is assigned to before global declaration", and attempts to declare as: "global summary = ' '.join(preSumm)".        (The issue lies in the following: I can call them all together in a single button, but attempts at separating each one into their own separete buttons cause falure; being caused by the need to access the processed variable 'done' to the textPDF function)